# Is there any common SSO endpoint for Communities and Salesforce

Tags: community, connected-apps, saml

We have a connected app which uses SAML which renders data from an external application in an Iframe and it's working fine inside Salesforce.

Now the challenge which we are facing is; we also want community users to see data from the external app through communities but, since both Salesforce and Community domain names are different both will have different endpoints and the external app is not able to hit different IDP endpoints.

Example:
Salesforce EndPoint: https://org.my.salesforce.com/idp/login?app=0sp280000004DaP
Community 1 EndPoint: https://community.force.com/community1/idp/login?app=0sp280000004DaP
Community 2 EndPoint: https://community.force.com/community2/idp/login?app=0sp280000004DaP

Is there any common endpoint which i can use for both Salesforce and Community?
Or Any other solution for this problem?

Thanks,
Sachin.